# Finding Top 10 countries

Tags: python, json, dataframe

Can someone help me on this. I am trying to find top 10 countries with most projects from a dataframe (loaded from Json).

I used this query: `json_df.groupby('countrycode').max()` but this results in multiple rows not sure why. These are the columns I have:

```py
Index(['_id', 'approvalfy', 'board_approval_month', 'boardapprovaldate',
       'borrower', 'closingdate', 'country_namecode', 'countrycode',
       'countryname', 'countryshortname', 'docty', 'envassesmentcategorycode',
       'grantamt', 'ibrdcommamt', 'id', 'idacommamt', 'impagency',
       'lendinginstr', 'lendinginstrtype', 'lendprojectcost',
       'majorsector_percent', 'mjsector_namecode', 'mjtheme',
       'mjtheme_namecode', 'mjthemecode', 'prodline', 'prodlinetext',
       'productlinetype', 'project_abstract', 'project_name', 'projectdocs',
       'projectfinancialtype', 'projectstatusdisplay', 'regionname', 'sector',
       'sector1', 'sector2', 'sector3', 'sector4', 'sector_namecode',
       'sectorcode', 'source', 'status', 'supplementprojectflg', 'theme1',
       'theme_namecode', 'themecode', 'totalamt', 'totalcommamt', 'url'])
```

Comment: Can you add detail information? Example of json and your code. The runnable(by itself) code could be best.

Comment: This is the code I used:
```import pandas as pd
import json
json_df=pd.read_json('data/world_bank_projects.json')
json_df.groupby('countrycode').max()```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
json_df = json_df[['countrycode','_id']].groupby(['countrycode']).agg(['count'])
```

It gives the output showing how many projects are related to each countrycode.